# Query for Parent custom object and Standard child Object

Tags: soql, administration

I have a Parent custom object called `New_Country_c` and standard `contact` Object. I need to write a query to count of all contacts related to `New_Country_c`. I have tried following the query but does not work. Can anyone what I am missing. it is filtered lookup field in contact.

`SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM contact) FROM New_Country_c`

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this query in two ways.

### Parent-Child Query

You're currently writing the query in parent-child form. If you do so, you're required to write the subquery against the **relationship name**, not the **child object name**. The relationship name can be found on the lookup field from child to parent.

Your child subquery should use this relationship name postfixed with __r in the FROM clause. It would look something like

```
 SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts__r) FROM New_Country_c
```

Your returned `List<New_Country__c>` result would contain `New_Country__c` records, each of which would have a property `Contacts__r` that is typed as a `List<Contact>`. You can ask each of those properties for its `size()`.

For more details, make sure to read [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) from the SOQL and SOSL Reference.

### Aggregate Query

An aggregate query is a more direct way to get this information, while querying less data from the database. You write your aggregate query against the child object, and include a `GROUP BY` clause against the field that looks up to the parent.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) count, New_Country__c country FROM Contact GROUP BY New_Country__c
```

This will yield you a `List<AggregateResult>`, each of whose component `AggregateResult` records has a `count` and a `country` property.

See [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) and [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm#!) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate the records of `New_Country_c` with loop and retrieve the size of the child record list.

```
for(New_Country_c nc: [SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM contacts) FROM New_Country_c]){
    System.debug(nc.contacts.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), New_Country__c FROM Contact GROUP BY New_Country__c
```

Comment: Hi @vm53, this looks like a correct answer to me, but it will be of more value to the asker and the community if you add some *explanation* of why this is a correct approach, and perhaps a reference documentation link.